# CakePHP 2.x containable behavior conditions on deep associations

Tags: cakephp

I have model relations like this:

`Project` hasMany `SubProject` hasMany `Item`

I want to set up a `containable` array so that I can find all of the `Item`s which belong to a particular `Project`, and paginate the results. So, in my `ItemsController` I have:

```
public $paginate = array(
  'Item' => array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => array('
      'Item.create_time' => 'desc'
    ),
    'contain' => array(
      'SubProject' => array(
        'Project'
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Somewhere, obviously, I need to place a condition like `"SubProject.project_id = $pid"`, but nothing I've tried yields the correct results. The best I can manage is results that look like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Item] => Array
            (
                [id] => 13
                [file_name] => foo.tar.gz
                .... other keys ...
                [create_time] => 2013-01-23 14:59:49
                [subProject_id] => 4
            )

        [SubProject] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [name] => foo
                [project_id] => 2
                ..... other keys ....
                [Project] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )
 [1] => Array
 .....
```

**Edit**: It is quite correctly omitting the Project record that doesn't match; I want to skip any Item records with out a matching Project record.

It has crossed my mind to [manually specify my joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249978/cakephp-conditions-on-deep-model-associations), but I feel like that shouldn't be necessary.

It seems like this should be obvious, but alas, the solution escapes me.

Comment: There's really nothing to the models beyond the `hasMany` relations I mentioned in the question (and the associated `belongsTo` relations).

Comment: Why not to find subproyects with $pid, then extracting $subpids (maybe with Set::extract), and then paginate Items with $subpids?

Comment: I suppose that's possible, but isn't this the sort of search that Containable is designed for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did eventually solve this problem, so I thought I'd explain what I did in the hope it might help someone else.

After reading [this blog post by Mark Story](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations) (which is from the days of 1.2 but still relevant) I decided that the thing to do was create a custom find type in my Item model that binds the Project model directly. This gives a first-level association that Containable can filter correctly.

So, in the Items model, I have something like the following (see [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#creating-custom-find-types) on custom find types).

```
public $findMethods = array('byProject' => true);

public function _findByProject($state, $query, $results=array()) {
    if ($state == 'before') {
        $this->bindModel(array(
            'hasOne' => array(
                'Project' => array(
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'conditions' => array('Project.id = SubProject.project_id')
                )
            )
        ));
        return $query;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Note that setting `foreignKey` to false is necessary to prevent CakePHP from trying to automatically use a non-existent database key. In the ItemsController, the pagination options now look like this:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'Item' => array(
        'findType' => 'byProject',
        'limit' => 10,
        'order' => array(
            'Item.create_time' => 'desc'
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'SubProject',
            'Project'
        ),
        'conditions' => array('Project.id' = $pid)
    ),
);
```

...where `$pid` is the id of the project to display. Some minor tweaks in the view code to accomodate the slightly different results array structure, and I was all set.

Comment: `foreignKey false` is only required because you've used hasOne. if you use belongsTo, it wouldn't be necessary to specify the key or conditions since `project_id` is the default key

Comment: Good point. Also, I should mention that this has the added benefit of being more efficient in the sense that the find only generates a single SQL query.

Comment: Just because you can get the data in one query doesn't mean it's the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT ===============

```
public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => 'Item.create_time DESC',      //'order' => array(''Item.create_time' => 'desc'),
    'contain' => array(
        'SubProject' => array(
            'Project' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'id' => $project_id    // Passed parameter
                )
            )
        )
     )
);
```

=================================================

Have you tried using `conditions` as in the following? Also, I did not write the 'order' section of the code the way you have it.

```
public $paginate = array(
    'Item' => array(
        'limit' => 10,
        'order' => 'Item.create_time DESC',      //'order' => array(''Item.create_time' => 'desc'),
        'contain' => array(
            'SubProject' => array(
                'Project' => array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'id' => $project_id    // Passed parameter
                    )
                )
            )
        )
     )
);
```

Comment: Yes, this is among the many things I've tried (and I just checked it again). The results still include all of the `Item` entries, as I explained in my question (I'll edit that part for clarity).

Comment: Ok...Perhaps you shouldnt include `Item` in this as you are calling it from an `ItemsController` function... I will update my Answer with what I mean

Comment: Doesn't make any difference—and as it says [in the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#query-setup), inclusion of the model name as top level key is valid so you can set pagination options for multiple models.

Comment: +1 for helping me think this through, I really appreciate it. The solution was somewhat different in the end. I've posted it as another answer.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Something else to learn from!