# CakePHP 2.3: Filter find results based on current user

Tags: cakephp

I have models with the the following relations, defining a situation where users can belong to many groups, and multiple groups can be granted access to a project.

`User` HABTM `Group` HABTM `Project`

I would like to set things up so that any `find()` done on the Project model will only return results to which the current user has access, based on her group membership.

My first thought is to use the `beforeFind()` callback to modify the query. However, the two-level association has me stumped. I solved a similar problem (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528492/cakephp-2-x-containable-behavior-conditions-on-deep-associations/14542665#14542665)) by rebinding models. However, that was for a custom find method—I don't think that approach will work in a general situation like this where I need to modify arbitrary queries.

Using `afterFind()` to filter results isn't a good idea because it will confuse pagination (for example) when it doesn't return the right number of records.

Finally, I have a nagging suspicion that I'm trying to re-invent the wheel. The access control I've seen in CakePHP (e.g. Cake ACLs) has been at the controller/action level rather than at the model/record level, but I feel like this should be a solved problem.

**Edit:** I eventually decided that this was over-complicated and just added a `getAccessibleByUser($id)` method to my Project model. However, I'm still curious whether it's possible to globally add this kind of restriction to all `find()` operations. It seems like exactly the sort of thing you'd want to do in `beforeFind()`, and I suspect (as DavidYell suggests below) that the answer may lie with the Containable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the Containable behaviour. If you are using CakePHP 2.x then it comes in the box.

This behaviour allows you to manage the model relations and the data which is returned by them, along with allowing you to pass conditions, such as a group_id into your contain.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: I am already using the Containable behavior extensively. I have never managed to filter the top-level results based on a condition on a second-level association. (See the other question I linked to.) This is complicated by the fact that I want to add this restriction on arbitrary `find()` operations on the Project model.

Comment: Containable allows passing of conditions into the contained models. This will allow your filtering of contained models. Do be aware that about 3-4 contains Cake will start separating out the queries and aggregating the data afterwards. If this happens you will not be able to limit the results and you should switch over to using the Linkable behaviour to force a join and allow the conditions to be applied to the joined models.  If you are looking to adjust all your finds then I would suggest that you create a custom find method.