# find('all') conditions containing field of level-2 associated model

Tags: cakephp

I set up my models and and the following find() returns me the array underneath.

query:

```
find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Teamstarter.season' => $season),
    'contain' => array(
        'Teamstarter.Fflteam')
    )
);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Score] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [teamstarter_id] => 1
                    [roster_id] => 1
                    [score] => 
                    [position] => QB
                )

            [Teamstarter] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [season] => 2013
                    [gameday] => 1
                    [fflteam_id] => 1
                    [is_flex] => 0
                    [Fflteam] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [active] => 1
                            [name] => testteam11
                            [league_id] => 1
                        )

                )

        )
```

Now I want to add a condition for the league_id in the Fflteam Model. 
I tried to add

```
'Teamstarter.Fflteam.league_id' => $league
```

to the conditions array, but then I get an sql error that the column 'Teamstarter.Fflteam.league_id' could not be found.
How do I add a condition refering to fields in deeper levels.

Assosiations should be set correctly since the Models are found.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT

The Suggestion below just removes the Fflteam part

```
'contain' => array(
    'Teamstarter.Fflteam' => array(
        'conditions' => array(
           'Fflteam.league_id' => $league
        )
    )
)
```

result:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Score] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [teamstarter_id] => 1
                [roster_id] => 1
                [score] => 
                [position] => QB
            )

        [Teamstarter] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [season] => 2013
                [gameday] => 1
                [fflteam_id] => 1
                [is_flex] => 0
                [Fflteam] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )
```

But i don't want it to find the whole array entry. In this case for example if the league_id is 2 , the array should be empty not only the Fflteam part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in another thread:

[CakePHP 2.x containable behavior conditions on deep associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528492/cakephp-2-x-containable-behavior-conditions-on-deep-associations)

Here is the link which was in there:

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations

And here the code I used:

```
$this->unbindModel(array(
    'belongsTo' => array('Teamstarter')
));

$this->bindModel(array(
    'hasOne' => array(
        'Teamstarter' => array(
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Teamstarter.id = Score.teamstarter_id')
        ),
        'Fflteam' => array(
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Fflteam.id = Teamstarter.fflteam_id')
        )
)));

find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Teamstarter.season' => $season,
        'Fflteam.league_id' => $league),
    'contain' => array(
        'Teamstarter',
        'Fflteam')
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some like this:

```
'contain' => array(
    'Teamstarter.Fflteam' => array(
        'conditions' => array(
           'Fflteam.league_id' => $league
        )
    )
),
```

Or read great article: http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/09/05/example-of-cakephps-containable-for-deep-model-bindings/

Comment: this only removes the Fflteam model when the condition isnt met but not the Teamstarter model.

Comment: I was add link to article